# Ubuntu 18.10 not working on VMware 14.1.3

Tags: vmware, 18.10, vmware-workstation

I have a VMware workstation pro 14.1.3 on which I installed Ubuntu 18.04 then I updated the software, but as soon as it restarted (to finish updating) I cannot log in or do anything, it just stays on a Ubuntu screen. I tried editing

> open-vm-tools.service

file and it didn't work. What can I do to fix it? I have some important file in it. Can I re-install older version of Ubuntu without loosing data?

Comment: If all you want to do is rescue data, you could boot the VM from a LiveCD ISO, mount the virtual hard drive and copy your data elsewhere.

Comment: how can i do it can you explain the process

Answer (score 0):

In the virtual machine folder, check if you have 2 or 3 folders named "something.lck". If yes, delete them all (Don't worry, you won't lose any data, they are just temporary files) and check if the virtual machine works well after that.

Comment: it didnt help its still the same its stuck on purple screen